# How can I piece together string parameters to form an existing symbol?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a method which takes part of the name of something as a parameter and then pieces it together. Let's say I have three `arrays`:

> arrayA, arrayB, arrayC.

So, something like this:

```
public static void printArray(String id)
{
    System.out.println("Array " + id + ": " + Arrays.toString(array + id) );
}
```

Where I was hoping that running

```
printArray(C);
```

would turn `(array + id)` into arrayC and print the content of arrayC. Unfortunately it doesn't, and just says "array" is no recognized symbol.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is `array`? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, you should use a map

```
        String[] arrayA = {"a1", "a2", "a3"};               
        String[] arrayB = {"b1", "b2", "b3"};
        String[] arrayC = {"c1", "c2", "c3"};

        HashMap<String, String[]> mapArray = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        mapArray.put("A", arrayA);
        mapArray.put("B", arrayB);
        mapArray.put("C", arrayC);
```

when you want to retrieve your array

```
public static void printArray(String id)
{
    System.out.println("Array " + id + ": " + Arrays.toString(mapArray.get(id)));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

```
public class TestArray {
    String[] arrayA = new String[] { "A content" };
    String[] arrayB = new String[] { "B content" };
    String[] arrayC = new String[] { "C content" };

    public void printArray(String id) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        System.out.println("Array " + id + ": " + Arrays.toString((String[]) getClass().getDeclaredField("array" + id).get(this)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        (new TestArray()).printArray("C"); // prints "Array C: [C content]"
    }
}
```

But I think this is not really a good idea, and using a `HashMap` may be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), but you cannot reflect local variables and it sounds like you want to.

Your best bet may be to adjust `printArray` to take the array whose contents you want to dump:

```
public static void printArray(String id, Object[] array)
{
    System.out.println("Array " + id + ": " + Arrays.toString(array) );
}
```

Unfortunately, you'd need an overload for each primitive type if you want a generic solution:

```
public static void printArray(String id, boolean[] array){...}
public static void printArray(String id, char[] array){...}
public static void printArray(String id, double[] array){...}
...
```

You could keep the solution [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) by having a `private static` method that handled the formatting:

```
private static void outputArray( String arrayId, String arrayContents )
{
    System.out.println("Array " + arrayId + ": " + arrayContents );
}
```

Then adjust the `printArray` method(s) to call it:

```
public static void printArray(String id, Object[] array)
{
    outputArray(id, Arrays.toString(array) );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void printArray(String id)
    {
    System.out.println("Array " + id + ": content of Array" + id);
    }
```

will do the work.

In the toString method "array" is a variable, and it is not declared before, because of this you get the error message.

Edit:

```
public static void printArray(String id){
    if(id.equals("A")){
        // print the content of array A
    } else if(id.equals("B")){
        // print the content of array B
    } else if(id.equals("C")){
        // print the content of array C
    } else {
        System.out.println("I don't know that array");
    }
}
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Aha, I see. But this'll still just print

    "Array C: content of ArrayC"

and not the actual content though

Comment: if you want to get the content of an array, you need to write a loop to get the elements. i think i don't understand your request correctly